# Kingfisher - Cannot Load Image URL from Web

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of URL's I am trying to load into an ImageView using KingFisher.

```
arrPageTitle = ["This is The App Guruz", "This is Table Tennis 3D", "This is Hide Secrets"];
    arrPagePhoto = ["https://s3.amazonaws.com/fan-polls/heyward_again.jpg", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/fan-polls/Schwarber.jpg", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/fan-polls/mike_ditka.jpg"];
```

I am trying to load the appropriate image based on the index of the UIPageViewController:

```
pageContentViewController.imageView.kf_setImageWithURL((arrPagePhoto[index] as! String))
```

I am receiving `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: maybe use it in type of NSURL?

Comment: Can you post code?

Comment: which value are you getting nil?

Comment: How do I determine that? I am very new to swift and XCode

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu to learn about this specific Swift error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, `kf_setImageWithURL` require NSURL, not String.

So convert `arrPagePhoto[index]` to NSURL first then pass it to `kf_setImageWithURL`:

```
let downloadURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: arrPagePhoto[index])!

pageContentViewController.imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(downloadURL)
```